# Is there a step by step tutorial on how to compile from source for Monero cli on ubuntu 16?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, source, installation

Is there an easy to follow step by step guide on how to compile monero from source? Alot of the times I compiled previously it stops due to something missing, which goes for many times installing anything from source it seems.

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did on a ubuntu 16.04.

**Dependencies**

First I installed all the dependencies show [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#dependencies)

> sudo apt-get install libssl-dev build-essential cmake pkg-config libboost-all-dev libzmq3-dev libunbound-dev libsodium-dev

And build this dependency manually.

> sudo apt-get install libgtest-dev && cd /usr/src/gtest && sudo cmake . && sudo make && sudo mv libg* /usr/lib/

**Source Code**

Next get the source code via git.

> git clone --recursive https://github.com/monero-project/monero

If git is not found install it via

> sudo apt-get install git

Than go into the monero folder and build it via:

> cd monero
>
> make

On a oDroid c2 mini pc this took about 8-10 hours.

For me the tests fail in the end but the executables were in

```
monero/build/release/bin
```

All this information can be found in the readme from the monero repository [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero#compiling-monero-from-source)

Answer (score 0):

Compiling from source is not easy, even for experienced users.

You sure you want to compile from source or are you really asking how to get the Cli version working on your Ubuntu software?

Comment: yes i want to learn how to compile from source.

Answer (score 0):

If that's what you want, I would start Googling questions.  I don't think you'll find a step by step guide here.

Answer (score 0):

google:
monero compile site:github.com

Almost related
[Compile on Centos 6](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues/2085)

> Compile on Centos 6 #2085
>   @knutov opened this issue 
>   11 months ago
>
> How to compile on Centos 6?

Comment

> @moneromooo-monero
>   commented 11 months ago
>
> make, or make release-static
>
> Install all the things it needs and complains about.
>
> If errors which aren't due to missing dependencies, post here

Pretty much common way - fighting complains.